# How to find a Gridview Footer label when there isn't always a footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that I would like to extract the data in a footer from.

I have an issue as the footer doesn't always exist (for example if the gridview is empty).

How do I test for null against the label when the footer itself doesn't exist?

A simple if !null doesn't work as I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

```
if (GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TotalLbl") != null) //do stuff
```

Any pointers?

Comment: You need to check if GridView1.FooterRow is not null first.  So it'd look like this: `if(GridView1.FooterRow != null && GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TotalLbl") != null)`

Comment: Garrison, thats perfect thanks. Can't mark you as an answer but have upmarked your comment

Comment: Posted it as an answer.  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `GridView1.FooterRow` is not null first. So it'd look like this: `if(GridView1.FooterRow != null && GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TotalLbl") != null)`